# How to test with Codeception if the page has meta-tag?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, codeception, web-testing, webtest

e.g. to ensure that

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

does not exists on the page.

```
$I->wantTo('Check that page can be indexed');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->dontSeeInPageSource('<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />');
```

but it returns the error

> Call to undefined method WebGuy::dontSeeInPageSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$I->dontSeeElement('meta[name=robots]');
```

Comment: Meta elements are never visible so this assertion will pass regardless of whether the meta tag is present or not.

Answer (score 1):

To test it doesn't have the tag:

```
$I->dontSeeElementInDOM('meta[name=robots]');
```

To test it does have the tag:

```
$I->seeElementInDOM('meta[name=robots]');
```